# How can I use private (git repo) npm dependencies with fuzzy version matching?

Tags: node.js

This is specific to the `package.json` dependency resolver for the git repo syntax.

I know I can add dependencies to git repos with tags like such:

```
"dependencies": {
  "private-module": "git@github.com:sukima/private-module.git#1.2.3"
}
```

However, unlike a normal dependency you can't perform fuzzy matching on the version since the argument after the `#` is a specific tag. In other words `"private-module": "^1.2.3"` wouldn't work as expected.

How can I use things like `^1.2.3`, `>1.2.3`, and `~1.2.3` with private git repos that you don't want to publish to npmjs.org?

And if that isn't supported wouldn't the git repo syntax pretty much have the same tight coupling that a git submodule would?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `git` URLs, you are unfortunately limited to referencing either a specific branch, tag, or SHA, so using `semver` is not possible. To use semver, you'll need an actual NPM registry to reference. For instance, you could set up a private internal registry for your company. The docs have [more info](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry).

The key thing that you gain over submodules in the git-url case is simplified installation, and ease of dependency tracking. It means that if you `git clone` something with a `package.json` file, you can assume that all you need to do is `npm install`, without worrying about unknown dependencies pulled in via submodules. It also means all your packages can have hooks like installation-time compilation scripts, just like a normal npm package would.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issue and actually I've been confused since for me it works in some specific node/npm conditions. While running npm with node version 0.10.33 everything is being resolved correctly, however for node version 0.11.x and 0.12.x there is error caused by the carert/tilde sign being url-encoded which leads me to the conclusion that this is [a bug in node newer than 0.10.33](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9416).

Also the semver range specifier works as expected together with full git urls with no problem for bower.

**Edit:**
Since it seems unlikely to see the semver resolution for git urls in the very near future what came into my mind for private repo is to referene some branch or tag (here is how you can ['move' the remote tag](http://www.nax.cz/2011/01/15/move-a-remote-git-tag/)). Eg. having branch `stable` and just merging master to the `stable` branch each time we need the release and having dependency

```
"dependencies": {
  "private-module": "git@github.com:sukima/private-module.git#stable"
}
```

would do the job of being up to date to the recent version. Also it is possible to use more fancy branch naming to reflect many different 'release' versions we want to be synced with. Of course keeping the versioning in the package json is enough to verify the actual version being used.